# mongodb find() in insertOne() via nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a collecion in mongodb that contains categories and I have another collection that contains the companies. In the companies collection I have an array called 'categories' that contains the _id of the categories collection.

On the user interface the user can choose the category by the category name - and this will be posted to the server.

When I insert the payload into mongodb, I would like to implement some find() query inside the insertOne() function to get the _id of the category.

I can do this in noSqlBooster -

```
db.companies.insertOne({"key": db.categories.find({"categoryName":"thisCategory"}, {"categories_idToShowOnly":1}).limit(1)[0].categories_idToShowOnly});
```

and it will insert the value from otherCollection.

The question is - how can I achieve the same using nodejs?

When I try to insert any data into mongo like this -

```
var data = {
   "x": "y",
   "a": "b"
};

mongoClient.connect(config.mongoUrl.url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, (connectionError, db) => {
if (!connectionError) {
    var dbo = db.db(config.mongoUrl.db);
    dbo.collection(collection).insertOne(data, (insertError, insertResults) => {
        if (!insertError) {
            callback();
        }
    });
}
```

I have no problem, but I cannot put a mongodb query as a value in the data object.

I do not want to use eval for security reasons. Looking into storing function in mongodb server and run it but then I get the same point - can I put query in stored function?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the node.js driver for MongoDB. Find it in the below link
https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/
Also, find this tutorial link on how to start with it.
https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mongodb.asp

Comment: Bharath - maybe my question is not clear enough. Sorry for that.